# How to print a word in a list which has been assigned a random number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem.
In my piece of code that I am working on, I am creating a game upon which the user guesses a word from the list imported from a text file in python 3.3.  I choose a random word from the list e.g

```
words = random.randint(0,len(wordlist))
```

I have successfully, got the program working, however when the user gets the word wrong, it prints the random number its assigned to not the word from the list. for example

```
else:
    print("No, the answer was",words)
```

I was wondering how to get to print the word from the list not the random number?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a random number at all. Use the [`random.choice()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) instead:

```
words = random.choice(wordlist)
```

`random.choice()` picks a random *item* from the list.

Your use of `random.randint()` has two problems:

1. You now need to always use `wordlist[words]` each time you want the word; you are never really interested in random integer, so there is no point in storing that. But

   ```
   words = wordlist[random.randint(0, len(wordlist))]
   ```

   is rather more verbose than the `random.choice()` alternative.
2. `random.randint()` picks a number between the start and stop values, **inclusive**. That means you can end up picking exactly `len(wordlist)`, but there is no such index in your `wordlist` list; you'd get an `IndexError`. You need to use `random.randint(0, len(wordlist)) - 1`, really, or perhaps `random.randrange(len(wordlist))` instead.

   But again, `random.choice()` is just easier.

Comment: TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given, I am given this? thanks for you answer

Comment: @user3499206: you do have to call `random.choice(wordlist)` (that's one argument plus the `self` argument of a method), not `random.choice(0, len(wordlist))`.

Comment: print(wordlist[word])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str #this is when it goes to print it

Comment: @user3499206: that's because `word` *is your random word* already. Use `print(word)` instead.